# how can i show the previous value of a specific category while editing a category in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

When I want to edit a specific category I want to see the previous value of that category, but I don't get previous value of the category in the form.  I have used route model binding in `CategoryController`. The main part of the code is given bellow:

`Controller`:

```
public function edit(Category $category){
    return view('admin.editcategory',compact('category'));
}
```

`View`:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('Category.update',['category'=>$category]) }}" method="POST">
    @method('PATCH')
    <input type="text" name="category_name" value="{{ $category->category_name }}">
    {{ $errors->first('category_name') }}
    <textarea name="category_description" row="3">
        {{ $category->category_description }}
    </textarea>
    {{ $errors->first('category_description') }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Edit category</button>
    @csrf
</form>
```

`Route`:

```
Route::resource('Category','CategoryController');
```

Comment: `value="{{ $category->category_name }}"` should work. Can do a `dd($category)` before your `return view()` and add the output to your question?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing your Route Model binding, but it doesn't seem to be finding a `Category` with id of `1`; it's just returning a general instance, so `$category->{attribute}` is not outputting anything.

Comment: Can you add your route for the edit action to your question.

Comment: Category {#1155 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: [

Comment: @AsaduzzamanRabby Don't add code as a comment, edit your question and add it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In edit function passing the id of a category

```
public function edit($id){
     $category=Category::find($id);
    return view('admin.editcategory',compact('category'));
}
```

Comment: thaks you so much..It works.But i want to know why my code does not work...